# Developer Console Log Application 'Unknown'

Tags: developer-console

I have a question, why the application is named as Unknown? Im creating a new Account from an External App. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a field in the [Call Options Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_calloptions.htm), and optional. If the client chooses not to identify itself, then it will be listed as "Unknown." You might want to request a feature enhancement to specify the client so it will not show as "unknown."

Comment: Thanks! Im using a Custom REST API, how can I set that value?

Comment: @MartinGamboa Depends on your language of choice, but something like `request.setRequestHeader('Sforce-Call-Options', 'client=caseSensitiveToken')`. At least, I'm pretty sure that's how it goes. I haven't personally used this header before. Might be a different header.